# H2 refine XSLT to transform Shopify XML for FileMaker import

Tags: xslt, shopify, filemaker

I'm trying to transform the following Shopify XML ...

```
<orders>
  <order>
    <order-no>1001</order-no>
    <line-items>
      <line-item>
        <product-id>knife</product-id>
      </line-item>
      <line-item>
        <product-id>fork</product-id>
      </line-item>
    </line-items>
    <shipping-address>
      <post-code>rh10 3hs</post-code> 
    </shipping-address>
  </order>
</orders>
```

to the FileMaker FMPXMLRESULT grammer..

```
<ROW> 
  <COL>
    <DATA>1001</DATA>
  </COL>
  <COL>
    <DATA>Knife</DATA>
  </COL>
  <COL>
    <DATA>rh10 3hs</DATA>
  </COL>
</ROW>
<ROW> 
  <COL>
    <DATA>1001</DATA>
  </COL>
  <COL>
    <DATA>Fork</DATA>
  </COL>
  <COL>
    <DATA>rh10 3hs</DATA>
  </COL>
</ROW>
```

i.e.
1001 Knife rh10 3hs
1001 Fork rh10 3hs

using a FileMaker xslt example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">       
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
            <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="{count(/*/*)}" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
            <METADATA>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[position()=1]/*">
                    <FIELD>
                        <xsl:attribute name="EMPTYOK">YES</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MAXREPEAT">1</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">TEXT</xsl:attribute>
                    </FIELD>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET>
                <xsl:attribute name="FOUND"><xsl:value-of select="count(child::*)"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <ROW>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MODID">0</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="RECORDID">0</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                            <COL>
                                <DATA>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </DATA>
                            </COL>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BUT this extracts the top level order details for each order ignoring the children and grandchildren.

I'm a complete beginner and have trawled the net and forums trying many permutations of the line '' but to be honest it's guess work and initial elation is begin replaced by desperation ;-(

Any tips greatly appreciated

Many thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

In Filemaker, you can only import into one table at a time. You need a separate stylesheet for each import. This one for importing into the LineItems table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>

<METADATA>
<FIELD NAME="OrderID" TYPE="TEXT" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
<FIELD NAME="ProductID" TYPE="TEXT" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
</METADATA>

<RESULTSET FOUND="">

<xsl:for-each select="orders/order/line-items/line-item">

<ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../../order-no"/></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="product-id"/></DATA></COL>
</ROW>

</xsl:for-each>

</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this one for importing into the Orders table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>

<METADATA>
<FIELD NAME="OrderID" TYPE="TEXT" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
<FIELD NAME="PostCode" TYPE="TEXT" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
</METADATA>

<RESULTSET FOUND="">

<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">

<ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="order-no"/></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="shipping-address/post-code"/></DATA></COL>
</ROW>

</xsl:for-each>

</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```